# XMLHttpRequest2: словить пост запрос на сервере

Tags: javascript, html5, php

Всем доброго времени суток! Пытаюсь разобраться с `XMLHttpRequest2` но никак не получается словить пост запрос на сервере, уже вторую неделю бьюсь, всё без толку... С Firebug у меня что то не за ладилось, поэтому прошу конкретно указать ошибку и как в таком случае нужно писать.
К делу!
Есть форма:

```
<form>
 <input type='text' name='text'> 
 <div onClick='postMessege(this.form);'>Отправить</div>
</form>
```

Вот собственно и сам XHR2:

```
function postMessege(form) {
 var formData=new FormData(form),
     xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('POST', 'handlers/postpmessege.php', true);
 xhr.onload = function(e){
  alert(this.response);
 };
 xhr.send(formData);
};
```

Обработчик на PHP:

```
<?php
 $text=$_POST['text'];
 echo"$text";
?>
```

Не видит приходящую переменную $_POST['text'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве кнопки используйте элемент формы, а не div. Напр.,

```
<input type="button" onclick="postMessege(this.form);" value="Отправить">
```

А если все-таки хотите div, то так:

```
<div onclick="postMessege(this.parentNode);">Отправить</div>
```

Comment: я бы  на submit бы вешал сиё

Comment: а как это сделать на submit если он страницу перезагружает ?

Comment: @Станислав Далинин, **event.preventDefault**

Comment: Deonis - Спасибо огромное! Заработало! А я дурак мучился)